# Laravel listener not working, column not updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I created a listener that updates a field in the database when a new user is created. THis is my event.

```
class NewUser
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public $user;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
}
}
```

and my listener

```
 public function handle(NewUser $event)
{
    $captainrefid = DB::table('users')->where('referral_id', $event->user->referred_by)->value('referral_id');
    $capdownlnrs = DB::table('users')->where('upliner', $captainrefid)->get();
    if(count($capdownlnrs) > 2){
        return DB::table('users')->where('id', $event->user->id)->update(['upliner' => $captainrefid]);
    }
```

this is my event service provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as 
ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{ 
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\NewUser' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserPairingAndSpillover',
    ],
];

/**
 * Register any events for your application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    //
}
}
```

it is register in the user model.

```
protected $events = [
    'created' => Events\NewUser::class
];
```

it does not give any error though. Yet the column us the database is not updating. Can anyone help me as to why? I do not have to queue it compulsorily.

Comment: Have you defined the handler and initialized the events ?

Comment: Yes i have. In the events service provider

Comment: Have you checked the execution comes into handle function ?

Comment: Yes i have. Will i need to queue it or something?

Comment: Show where you register the event listener, where you're firing the event and how you're creating your user.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: You have to create a User via his model to trigger 'created'. Do you?